# Number of elements less than a key in multiset

Tags: c++, big-o, multiset, lower-bound

I have a multiset and I would like to know how many elements are less than a key in O(1) time.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    multiset<int> s;
    s.insert(1);
    s.insert(3);
    s.insert(4);
    s.insert(3);
    s.insert(6);
    s.insert(4);

    cout << "The multiset elements are: ";
    for (auto it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); it++)
        cout << *it << " ";

    auto it = s.lower_bound(4);
    cout << "\nThe lower bound of key 4 is ";
    cout << (*it) << endl;
    
    // How to find number of elements smaller than 4?
    return 0;
}
```

I know about a function called distance(s.begin(), it) which will give me the answer in O(n) time but that's not nice.

Comment: This is not likely possible with a `multiset`, even if you had access to the internal tree structure of the typical implementation.

Comment: There's no good way of doing this I'm afraid. `distance` is `O(n)` for a reason.

Comment: you can maybe store elements in `vector`, then [sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) it before applying [lower_bind](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound). then the number of elements calculation would be `O(1)` but the other use cases of course may get worse  compared to `multiset`.

Comment: I think you mean something more like "elements less than a given element" or "elements less than a key, given an iterator to the lower bound". Otherwise, finding the lower bound counts against your complexity, forcing at least O(lg n).

Comment: Is the loop that outputs the element of the multiset just for demonstration, or is it a real part of your end goal? I ask because that is already an O(n) operation, so what would be the big deal about adding another O(n) operation? Even better, if that loop is needed, why not calculate the number of elements smaller than 4 (and the lower bound, for that matter) in the same loop?

Comment: No that loop is just for demonstration purposes and not intended in the actual code

Comment: If you need the dynamic manipulation of a multiset, use an order-statistic tree.  Otherwise, use a hash table of the ordinals to get actual *O*(1) lookup.